# How to save IDirect3DSurface9 or LPD3DXBUFFER to memory as JPG

Tags: c++, jpeg, directx-9

I'm trying to capture game screenshot, i have that code:

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Device;
D3DSURFACE_DESC screenDescription;

...

void Capture(){
    IDirect3DSurface9* pRenderTarget;
    IDirect3DSurface9* pDestTarget;

    Device->GetRenderTarget(0, &pRenderTarget);
    pRenderTarget->GetDesc(&screenDescription);

    Device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(screenDescription.Width, screenDescription.Height, screenDescription.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pDestTarget, NULL);
    Device->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_FORCE_DWORD, &pDestTarget);

    char tName[200];
    sprintf(tName, "%s_%d.jpg", "C:\\test", GetTickCount());
    D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileA(tName, D3DXIFF_JPG, pDestTarget, NULL, NULL);

    //LPD3DXBUFFER buffer;
    //D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory(&buffer, D3DXIFF_JPG, pDestTarget, NULL, NULL);

    pRenderTarget->Release();
    pDestTarget->Release();

    isCapturing = false;
}
```

---

Saving to file with `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileA` works perfectly, but i want to save captured image and write them to end of another file on disk, not creating a new once.
Is there a way how convert `IDirect3DSurface9` or `LPD3DXBUFFER` to **JPG** bytes?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i'm found this code and he works:

```
LPD3DXBUFFER buffer;
D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory(&buffer, D3DXIFF_JPG, pDestTarget, NULL, NULL);
DWORD imSize = buffer->GetBufferSize();
void* imgBuffer = buffer->GetBufferPointer();

std::fstream out;
out.open(tName, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out);
out.write((char*)imgBuffer, imSize);
out.clear();
out.close();
```